# Initializing private member static const array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initialization, static-members

```
class MyClass
{
public:
         ...
private:
    enum class BDTNodeType : unsigned char
    {
        NT_TERMINAL_ZERO,
        NT_TERMINAL_ONE,
        NT_TERMINAL_X,
        NT_NOT_TERMINAL
    };

    class BDTNode
    {
    public:
        explicit BDTNode(BDTNodeType node_type = BDTNodeType::NT_NOT_TERMINAL);
        BDTNode(const BDTNode &node);
        ~BDTNode();

        BDTNodeType type;
        BDTNode *thenPtr;   //1
        BDTNode *elsePtr;   //0
    };

    BDTNode *root_node;

    //Constant nodes
    static const BDTNode fv_nodes[3] = {
        BDTNode(BDTNodeType::NT_TERMINAL_ZERO),
        BDTNode(BDTNodeType::NT_TERMINAL_ONE),
        BDTNode(BDTNodeType::NT_TERMINAL_X)
    };
};
```

I want to initialize static const BDTNode fv_nodes array directly inside the class declaration, since C++11 allows to do this. But I get "C2864: 'MyClass::fv_nodes' : a static data member with an in-class initializer must have non-volatile const integral". And I can't initialize it outside class, because in that case "BDTNode" class would be inaccessible. So how should I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> C++11 allows to do this

No, C++11 doesn't allow this. You may be thinking of **non-static** member initialisers, which are allowed as an alternative to initialisation in a constructor.

For static members, the rules haven't changed much. The in-class declaration is not a definition and, unless it's a non-volatile const integral or enumeration type and not odr-used, it needs a single definition outside the class. If you provide an initialiser, that goes on the definition.

> And I can't initialize it outside class, because in that case "BDTNode" class would be inaccessible.

No, the initialiser is in the scope of the class, so private names are accessible. The following [works for me](http://ideone.com/D6UYXM):

```
// in class
static const BDTNode fv_nodes[3];

// in a source file
const MyClass::BDTNode MyClass::fv_nodes[3] = {
    BDTNode(BDTNodeType::NT_TERMINAL_ZERO),
    BDTNode(BDTNodeType::NT_TERMINAL_ONE),
    BDTNode(BDTNodeType::NT_TERMINAL_X)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

but you can do this with a static function if you wish:

This *did* change in c++11 in that it because thread-safe without the explicit use of a mutex.

```
#include <array>

class MyClass
{
public:
    //    ...
private:
    enum class BDTNodeType : unsigned char
    {
        NT_TERMINAL_ZERO,
        NT_TERMINAL_ONE,
        NT_TERMINAL_X,
        NT_NOT_TERMINAL
    };

    class BDTNode
    {
    public:
        explicit BDTNode(BDTNodeType node_type = BDTNodeType::NT_NOT_TERMINAL);
        BDTNode(const BDTNode &node);
        ~BDTNode();

        BDTNodeType type;
        BDTNode *thenPtr;   //1
        BDTNode *elsePtr;   //0
    };

    BDTNode *root_node;

    static const std::array<BDTNode, 3>& fv_nodes() {
        static const std::array<BDTNode, 3> _fv_nodes {
            BDTNode(BDTNodeType::NT_TERMINAL_ZERO),
            BDTNode(BDTNodeType::NT_TERMINAL_ONE),
            BDTNode(BDTNodeType::NT_TERMINAL_X)
        };
        return _fv_nodes;
    }

    static const BDTNode& fv_node(size_t i) {
        assert(i < 3);
        return fv_nodes()[i];
    }
};
```