# Initializing a static class member array with a non-trivial expression in C++11

Tags: c++11, clang++

I would like to benchmark the performance of using a const cache for some static function inside a cache. So I have something like that:

```
class Foo {

    static double cost(int factor) { <moderately complex function> };

    // Other stuff using the cost() function

};
```

And I would like to benchmark against an alternative version like this one:

```
class Foo {
    private:
        static double _cost(int factor) { <same function as before> };
        static const double cost_cache[MAX_FACTOR] = ???;
    public:
        static double cost(int factor) { return cost_cache[factor]; };
    // Other stuff
}
```

With a way to initialize my cost_cache array in a way equivalent to

```
for (int idx = 0; i < MAX_FACTOR; ++i)
    cost_cache[idx] = _cost(idx);
```

In a high-level functional language I would use a map primitive. How do I properly initialize that in C++11 (or C++14 ?) I saw other posts addressing similar questions, like [Initializing private member static const array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569249/), but its solution is inapplicable in my case, I can't put the 10k values verbatim in source.

I'm using `clang++`

Answer (score 0):

What about first initialize the array with "{}",
and then overwrite elements by a method that loads values from a file?

Comment: But AFAIK that would require dropping the `const` modifier from the array, and I don't want to lose that type safety.